# User Permissions for Sharing Reports and Dashboards

Tags: permissions, profile, dashboard

I want to give specific profiles in my organization the ability to modify and use Dynamic Dashboards.

According to this [Salesforce Help Page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=analytics_sharing_permissions.htm&language=en_US), I need to give the following permissions to the profiles.

- Create and Customize Dashboards
- Create Dashboard Folders
- Edit My Dashboards
- Manage Dashboards in Public Folders
- View Dashboards in Public Folders

However, I do not see any of these options on profile permissions.  What I see that seems relevant:

- Manage Dashboards
- Manage Dynamic Dashboards
- Run Reports

**How do I enable the 5 permissions I listed above for profiles?**

here are some screenshots of what I see.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Questions:  1)  What edition are you using?  2)  Are these custom profiles?  3)  Are you using enhanced setup?

Comment: @HomerJ Developer Edition, yes they are custom profiles, and I'm not entirely sure if I am, but I'm leaning towards yes haha

Comment: The way you'd tell, is if you open a profile, do you have an "EDIT" button at the top of the screen, or is there an APPS and SYSTEM section, with additional menus?

Comment: @HomerJ there is an edit button :)

Comment: Strange.  When you edit the profile, in the Administrative section, you should be seeing all of the options if the profile is a "salesforce" User License profile.  Another question, is the dev org recently created?

Comment: @HomerJ it's anywhere between 6 - 10 months old.   It's Salesforce / Salesforce Platform user license.

Answer (score 0):

Go to user management settings and toggle Enhanced Profile User Interface to change this view